# How to create a simple "spot light" effect with Sdl or Sdl.Net?

Tags: lighting, sdl

i'm wondering: how to create a simple "car headlight" (for i.e) or a torch spotlight in Sdl or Sdl.NET ?
Does anyone know how ?
Thanks

Comment: 2d or 3d? screenshots or youtube vids on what you're looking for? (yes, I understand this is a 2 year old question..)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the light as a translucent image, e.g. a .png with an alpha channel. Then you just rotate it to point to your looking direction.